# Browsing Windows Phone 8 file system in the emulator

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is there a way to browse the file system of Windows Phone 8 running in the emulator, preferably while the emulator is running?

It would make debugging much easier if I could access the application local storage and its other private folders while the application is running: check the files that are present, modify them, add new ones etc. On more than one occasion this proved useful to me with Windows Store apps for Windows 8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368406/where-is-isolated-storage-from-wp8-emulator-located-on-pcsolved

Check this link it contains answer for your question..

Comment: that question has been removed...

Comment: Update for Windows 10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) integrated file browser.

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can use built-in tool ISETool.exe (only command line):

[How to use the Isolated Storage Explorer tool for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Best regards

Comment: While the WP Power Tools seems to be for XAML only apps, the newer version of this tool works perfectly on WinPhone 8.1 apps (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629254.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to use ISETool to browse any folder besides a specific app's? For instance, I'd like to upload a .html file and open it with the phone's browser.