# Sqlite error WP8.1

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing Windows phone 8.1 app. I have problem with Sqlite database. I created one, and made file. Now i want to use that file in my app, and get data from it.

I did create like this:

```
 SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(@"C:\ProbaProbe\MySql.sqlite");

 SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\ProbaProbe\MySql.sqlite;Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        string sql = "create table highscores (name varchar(20), score int)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And i inserted some data with INSERT statment. That works nice.
Now, when i want to use that MySql.sqlite in Windows Phone 8.1 app, i have problems. I did this way:

```
 private async Task CopyDatabase()
    {
        string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(@"C:\ProbaProbe\MySql.sqlite");
        bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = true;
            grad q = new grad();
            SQLiteCommand sqlComm = new SQLiteCommand(db);   
            string a = (db.Query<grad>("select * from grad")[0]).Ime;
        catch
        {
            isDatabaseExisting = false;
        }


    }
```

Problem is: 
Could not open database file: C:\ProbaProbe\MySql.sqlite (CannotOpen)

I think i'm missing something...
Anyone?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can't access system directories on Windows Phone. Applications on WP work in sandbox, so you can only access local storage available only for your application.

You could use connection string like this ([Local database for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202861(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Examples)):

`isostore:/MySql.sqlite`

If you need to copy your database file into phone's or emulator's storage you could use [Windows Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I forgot to say, I'm working on Emulator at the moment. And also, I have this class with get/set "grad"...

Comment: Emulator emulates the system, so it's the same ;-). If you need to access emulator's storage try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013225/browsing-windows-phone-8-file-system-in-the-emulator

Comment: @BojanZloporubovic does it answer your question?

Comment: Still not. I tried: "ms-appx:///MySql.sqlite" and "isostore:/MySql.sqlite" not working. 
And when i tried to copy MySql.sqlite on actual device, my tables gone. It's empty base. I have no idea why...
Any ideas?

Comment: Not working means "Could not open database file"? For existing DB make sure that you copied it in a right place (try to move it to "Shared" directory). Why you can't create a DB from the application?

Comment: It's opened DB, but it's empty
This is what i need to do. I have webservice, and from that i create DB and save it to disk. And after that need to use that DB on device (Windows Phone 8.1). 
And i tried to multiple location to copy, but no luck... :(
Tried path like: "This PC\Windows Phone\Phone\Test\MySql.sqlite", but nothing.
The funny thing is, that i succeed to connect, but my DB is empty....

Comment: With this: "string DB_PATH = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "MySql.sqlite"));" path is good, and works. 
But, when i get to this:
"var tp = dbConn.Query<grad>("select * from grad").FirstOrDefault();"
it's says: tp = null